# How to detect and debug strong reference cycles in Swift?

Tags: profiling, swift, memory-profiling

In simple cases it as trivial as an intense stare at a few lines of code:

```
class A {
    var b: B?
}

class B {
  var a: A?
}

var a = A()
var b = B()
a.b = b
b.a = a
```

How to solve this problem for >50k lines of code project (porting from Objective-C/C++). For example, is there a way to develop a tool to traverse an object graph at the run time (as is done in Java/C# worlds)?

Comment: The same problem already applies to the original Objective-C if it is ARC. Keep that in mind while looking for solutions. There are many more resources for Objective-C available. :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of implementing an object graph traversal, you can detect strong reference cycles with instruments : it identifies memory leaks and can graphically show the cycles ([Apple instruments documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4))

You should replace every objective C weak property by a weak instance variable in Swift

```
    class B {
      weak var a: A?
    }
```

and if you can be sure that it never takes nil as a value you can prefix it by unowned

```
    class B {
      unowned var a: A
    }
```

you could then access the property without having to force-unwrap the variable with a !

There might be more to it if your objective-C code uses @properties attributes that were the norm before arc

Comment: Thanks for the link to the instruments! I am checking whether it works with Swift